# Ajax pagination wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an issue with my ajax pagination on wordpress :

```
$(function($) {   
    // When i click on pagination link  
    $('.last-news').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e){
        // I remove the default behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // Then i add a smoothscroll to the top
        var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(),
            $content = $('.last-news .content');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop:$("#last-news").offset().top   
        }, 400); 

        // There is the ajax code where i get the content of my link
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        // I fadeOut the content before i fadeIn the new one
        $content.fadeOut(200, function(){
            // I call the content of my link
            $content.load(link + '.last-news .content', function() {
                $content.fadeIn(200);
                // I change the url without refreshing the page
                history.pushState(null, null, link);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

- The url of my page is like : localhost/my_site/page/x
- The pagination works well without javascript
- This code worked strangely when i had this type of permalink: localhost/my_site/?&paged=x (The x+1/x-1 and next/prev links worked but when i called the last page nothing happened)
- Now i have an error when i console.log the error of .load() ("error")

How can i debug this? (Im not familliar enough with ajax :s).

Do you have any idea what i can try to fix it?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried adding a space here: `$content.load(link + ' .last-news .content', function()` before `.last-news`?

Comment: I just did and now its working like my previous permalink: The x+1/x-1 and next/prev links work but when i call the last page, i have the fadeOut/fadeIn animation but it's staying on the same page (and the link changed)..
Better but still buggy!

Comment: I tested a littler deeper my pagination: i have 36pages, my next/prev and x+1/x-1 links work only until i arrive on page 33, after i have to refresh the page to get my content. My first page link works everytime. My next-post-link and prev-post link inside my single.php post work (without ajax) well even though theses posts are on the page > 33..

Comment: New update: it appears that the last 3 pages isn't loaded at all. I remove page by page to come back to 30pages and everytime the last 3pages isn't loaded.. I made a condition to set window.location.href to refresh the page if i have an "error" but it's kinda hacky and i would like to understand why i have this result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i fixed it!

As my url was correct i had to change the header of the server's response to `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` before **any code** of my header.php file

I don't really know if i will need to remove it when i will come to prod, or if that will make another issues but, now it's fully working. Hope i could avoid someone else wasting time on this :)